# Performing Background Tasks in Django

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-views

I need help with the following problem.

I am working on a Django site. My page requires users to complete a form. My view then processes this form information. Part of this involves processing large files which takes a long time. I want to be able to return a thank-you page as soon as the form is submitted but then process the data afterwards in the same view. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be, once the form has been submitted, delegate the processing of the forms data to a separate thread. This will allow you to then redirect the user to the thank you page  whilst the processing happens in the background.

This stack overflow question on [background threads in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168508/background-function-in-python) gives a quick introduction into a simple way of accomplishing this. Also, this article on [background task processing and deferred execution in Django](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/django-celery-rabbitmq) introduces a more sophisticated approach.