# Python: how to use `multiprocessing` to run background tasks?

Tags: python, python-multithreading, python-multiprocessing

The pros and cons of `multiprocessing` versus `threading` are discussed here: [Multiprocessing vs Threading Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044580/multiprocessing-vs-threading-python)

I'd like to use `multiprocessing` to perform a task in the background, while continuing on with the rest of the program. This problem was solved in the following question question using `threading`: [background function in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168508/background-function-in-python)

```
import threading

def function_A(some_args):
    # some stuff

def function_B(some_args):
    #do some stuff
    my_thread = threading.Thread(target=function_A, args=my_args)
    my_thread.start()
    #continue doing stuff
```

Here's my attempt using `multiprocessing`:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def function_A(some_args):
    # some stuff

worker_pool = mp.Pool(processes=4)

def function_B(some_args, worker_pool):
    # do some stuff
    worker_pool.apply_async(function_A, args=my_args)
    # continue doing stuff
```

I tried this out in a test script:

```
import threading
import multiprocessing
import time


def function_A(task_description, sleep_time):
    time.sleep(sleep_time)
    print "function_A with task {} completed!\n".format(task_description)

def function_threading(sleep_time):
    st = time.time()

    for x in xrange(4):
        print "Calling A and continuing (threading)..."
        print "Time between calls: ", round(time.time() - st, 3)        
        a_thread = threading.Thread(target=function_A, args=("threading {}".format(x), sleep_time,))
        a_thread.start()
        st = time.time()

def function_multiprocessing(sleep_time, worker_pool):
    st = time.time()

    for x in xrange(4):
        print "Calling A and continuing (multiprocessing)..."
        print "Time between calls: ", round(time.time() - st, 3) 
        worker_pool.apply_async(function_A, args=("multiprocessing {}".format(x), sleep_time,))
        st = time.time()

sleep_time = 2.5

# if __name__ == "__main__" statement required for multiprocessing on Windows
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "================================"
    print "Threading test."
    function_threading(sleep_time)
    print "================================"
    print "Multiprocessing test."
    worker_pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
    function_multiprocessing(sleep_time, worker_pool)
    print "================================"
```

Here's the output I get:

```
================================
Threading test.
Calling A and continuing (threading)...
Time between calls:  0.0
Calling A and continuing (threading)...
Time between calls:  0.0
Calling A and continuing (threading)...
Time between calls:  0.0
Calling A and continuing (threading)...
Time between calls:  0.001
================================
Multiprocessing test.
Calling A and continuing (multiprocessing)...
Time between calls:  0.0
Calling A and continuing (multiprocessing)...
Time between calls:  0.001
Calling A and continuing (multiprocessing)...
Time between calls:  0.0
Calling A and continuing (multiprocessing)...
Time between calls:  0.0
================================

function_A with task threading 0 completed!
function_A with task threading 2 completed!
function_A with task threading 1 completed!
function_A with task threading 3 completed!
```

Observations:

- there are child processes left hanging about even after the main process is killed -- is this from threading, or multiprocessing? I have to CTRL+ALT+DELETE and manually kill them
- the multiprocessing tasks never print

What needs to be fixed in order for the script to work? Or, put another way, how can I run and manage background processes using `multiprocessing`?

Comment: What, exactly, do you imagine `function_A()` to be doing?

Comment: But it didn't work. You never wait on the `AsyncResult` object returned by `apply_async` so your parent just exits.

Comment: @zxq9 `function_A` could be making a video (using `subprocess` to call `ffmpeg`) out  of images that `function_B` has left behind using data separate from what the main process is current working with

Comment: @tdelaney `function_A` doesn't return any results, so why should I wait for any results from it?

Comment: The problem is that the child processes are killed when the parent exits. You have an infinite loop in `function_A`. Fix that and add a print statement at the bottom. It won't print anything. Then add a time.sleep of. say, 15 seconds at the end of the main program and you will see the print.

Comment: @tdelaney I totally see what you mean; let me try that out again!

Comment: @tdelaney I fixed the infinite loop problem, and added some relevant print statements (see the edited code) based on your suggestion. As output, I see that the threading calls print something, but the multiprocessing calls never print anything...what's up with that?

Comment: It's been a long time since I did any multi processing in Python, but I seem to remember something about the child process not having a handle to stdout. You could try printing to a log file and see if that works.

Comment: This may be irrelevant, but I would like to mention  http://www.celeryproject.org