# What is the best way to repeatedly execute a function every few seconds, without intterupting other functions, for a Python gui?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, timer

I want to repeatedly run a function that retrieves data from an API every 60 seconds. However, I've realized that I can't put it to sleep, or use a while loop, without interrupting the other functions.

My question is, how do I repeatedly retrieve the data from the API/rerun the code that gets the data in the first place, without interrupting the other functions?

Comment: Are you creating a real-time dashboard, of sorts?

Comment: something like that

Comment: Well, the answer to your basic question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7168508

Comment: from what i've read from the link you provided, im kind of having a hard time seeing how they've implemented a timer..

Comment: They haven't.  But you still need a thread.  Your requirement was "without interrupting other functions."  For timers, look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393612/run-certain-code-every-n-seconds

Comment: With `tkinter`, use the universal widget [`after()`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) method, which won't interfere with the event-processing loop. You can also use threads, as long as they don't make any `tkinter` related calls (because it doesn't support multithreading).

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53697547/355230) for an example of using threads.

Answer (score 0):

below a complete script that retrieve ISS position longitude and latitude from Open Notify and print it on a thread.

I' ve set a 1 second time. You can start and stop the thread. Try now you to add your funcions.

Notice that you have to import this modules

> import requests
>
> import json

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import queue
import datetime
import time
import requests
import json

class MyThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, queue,):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

        self.queue = queue
        self.check = True
        
        
    def stop(self):
        self.check = False
        
    def run(self):
        
        while self.check:
            
            response = requests.get("http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json")
            data = response.json()
            time.sleep(1)
            self.queue.put(data)
                                    

class App(tk.Frame):
   
    def __init__(self,):
        
        super().__init__()

        self.master.title("Hello World")
        self.master.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",self.on_close)

        self.queue = queue.Queue()

        self.my_thread = None
    
        self.init_ui()
          
    def init_ui(self):

        self.f = tk.Frame()

        w = tk.Frame()

        tk.Button(w, text="Start", command=self.launch_thread).pack()
        tk.Button(w, text="Stop", command=self.stop_thread).pack()
        tk.Button(w, text="Close", command=self.on_close).pack()

        w.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=0)
        self.f.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=0)

    def launch_thread(self):

        if (threading.active_count()!=0):
            
            self.my_thread = MyThread(self.queue)
            self.my_thread.start()
            self.periodiccall()

    def stop_thread(self):
        if self.my_thread is not None:
            if(threading.active_count()!=1):
                self.my_thread.stop()


    def periodiccall(self):

        self.checkqueue()
        if self.my_thread.is_alive():
            self.after(1, self.periodiccall)
        else:
            pass

    def checkqueue(self):
        while self.queue.qsize():
            try:
                ret = self.queue.get(0)
                print("The ISS is currently over: {0} ".format(ret['iss_position']))
            except queue.Empty:
                pass                    
                   
    def on_close(self):
        if self.my_thread is not None:
            if(threading.active_count()!=1):
                self.my_thread.stop()

        self.master.destroy()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```