# How not to wait for a function to complete?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I have a list of links that I process with a function. But the problem is that it happens very slowly. How can I not wait for the function to complete? I apologize in advance, I'm new to this.

```py
import requests

def check(link):
    response = requests.get(link)
    print(response.text)

list = []
for link in list:
    check(link)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [background function in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168508/background-function-in-python)

Comment: Open your function in a Thread and continue processing in your main thread. (if you have a lot of calls, better use a Thread Pool with a limited number of threads, so that you won't create thousands of threads working concurrently)