# Data Frame to_sql without waiting for execution?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I was looking everywhere here, I can not find a way to perform a simple single line insert without waiting for respond, just keep executing next line :

```
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://' + username + ':' + password + '@/' + database + "?host=" + path)

    df.to_sql('queries', engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

This runs on a server to save some analytics to Postgresql, and i don't want to wait for respond, I also don't care if it failed here and there.

It is super important to me, to keep executing right after, and **spend no time** on this.

How to do this ?

Comment: Consider placing that block of code in a separate script and run script with `subprocess` [without waiting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3516007/1422451).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation [df.to_sql()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) does not support what you want. But there are some workarounds you can do:

1. Create a function that uses threading to insert this df to your db. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168508/background-function-in-python).
2. You can use async calls and sqlalchemy but you would need to map this dataframe to an object or something that sqlalchemy can work with.